# Why does my rig extend when I export

Tags: rigging, export

Whenever I export my rig all the end bones duplicate and add "_end". the rig works fine but it's only when I export.

### Images

[image: before I export] [image: After export]

### Here is the blender [file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1045VN7C0GOxZ5uiJGjmxpBoHeS681cvH?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is a limitation of the export format you are using, and doesn’t really have to do with blender. Ignore the end bones, and attempt posing the model.

Comment: yeah but this is a problem when I import it to unity where the duplicated bones disappear leaving the character without arms, head, or feet